# PHP: Control or something that can highlight differences in 2 strings?

Tags: php, comparison, highlight

I want to compare 2 strings and show the differences in a visual way using a php control. It should be something like a textarea that can highlight the differences. Is there something that either comes with standard PHP or something that can be added easily? Here is an example, it doesnt need to be that complex, but something similiar: http://rdxsoft.com/images/uploads/winmerge.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Text_Diff](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff) pear package.

**UPDATE**: I just found this native php function [xdiff_string_diff](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-string-diff.php) available from [xdiff pecl extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/xdiff).